# How to overcome regtlibv12 error and register a type library (OLE)?

Tags: ole, vb6

I am trying to setup a vb6 environment on Windows 10 machine and use it with some ocx components.

But whenever try to use regtlibv12.exe with any of the tlb files, I get error:

```
RegisterTypeLib of msdatsrc.tlb failed : 8002801c
```

[image: Registering of any tlb file does not seem to be well]

And I cannot use some of components in VB6 environment.

How to overcome this error, and what does this error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

The error is a permissions error, most likely.  Make sure you opened your command prompt with admin privileges.

Searching for regtlib*.exe from the \windows folder on deeper only produced regtlib.exe on my Windows 10 machine which also has VB 6.0.  I am fairly certain you can register a .tlb file with regsvr32 but you might also try the standard flavor of regtlib.exe which was in my Windows folder and dated 7/14/2000.